# How to mutate multiple variables without repeating codes?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm trying to create new variables from existing variables like below:

```
a1+a2=a3, b1+b2=b3, ..., z1+z2=z3
```

Here is an example data frame

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(1:10)))
colnames(df) <- c("a1","a2","b1","b2","c1","c2","d1","d2","e1","e2")
```

Here's my solution with repeating codes

```
# a solution by base R
df$a3 <- df$a1 + df$a2
df$b3 <- df$b1 + df$b2
df$c3 <- df$c1 + df$c2
df$d3 <- df$d1 + df$d2
df$e3 <- df$e1 + df$e2
```

Or

```
# a solution by dplyr
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(a3 = a1+a2,
         b3 = b1+b2,
         c3 = c1+c2,
         d3 = d1+d2,
         e3 = e1+d2)
```

Or

```
# a solution by data.table
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[,a3:=a1+a2][,b3:=b1+b2][,c3:=c1+c2][,d3:=d1+d2][,e3:=e1+e2]
```

Actually I have more than 100 variables, so I want to find a way to do so without repeating code... Although I tried to use mutate_ with standard evaluation and regular expression, I lost my way because I'm a newbie in R. Can you mutate multiple variables without repeating code?

Comment: Is the naming pattern always going to be like that? Meaning same first part of the name and then 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `data.table` solution:

```
sapply(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), function(ll) 
  df[ , paste0(ll, 3) := get(paste0(ll, 1)) + get(paste0(ll, 2))])
df[]
#     a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2 d1 d2 e1 e2 a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
#  1:  5  2  2  6  4  1 10  7  3  9  7  8  5 17 12
#  2:  4  8  7  3  3  7  9  6  9  7 12 10 10 15 16
#  3: 10  7  6 10  1  9  4  1  2  4 17 16 10  5  6
#  4:  3  4  1  7  6  4  7  4  7  5  7  8 10 11 12
#  5:  8  3  4  2  2  2  3  3  4 10 11  6  4  6 14
#  6:  6  6  5  1  8 10  1 10  5  3 12  6 18 11  8
#  7:  2 10  8  9  5  6  2  5 10  2 12 17 11  7 12
#  8:  1  1 10  8  9  5  6  9  6  8  2 18 14 15 14
#  9:  9  5  3  5 10  3  5  2  1  6 14  8 13  7  7
# 10:  7  9  9  4  7  8  8  8  8  1 16 13 15 16  9
```

Or, more extensibly:

```
sapply(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), function(ll) 
  df[ , paste0(ll, 3) := Reduce(`+`, mget(paste0(ll, 1:2)))])
```

If all of the variables fit the pattern of ending with `1` or `2`, you might try:

```
stems = unique(gsub("[0-9]", "", names(df)))
```

Then `sapply(stems, ...)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way using dplyr syntax??

Comment: I'm sure there is but I don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using `data.table`:

```
DT <- data.table(df)[, rn := .I]

DTadd3 <- dcast(melt(DT, measure.vars = 1:10)[, `:=` (let = substr(variable,1,1), rn = 1:.N), variable
                                              ][, s3 := sum(value), .(let,rn)], 
                rn ~ paste0(let,3), value.var = 's3', mean)

DT[DTadd3, on = 'rn'][, rn := NULL][]
```

which gives:

```
    a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2 d1 d2 e1 e2 a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
 1: 10  5  9  5 10  4  5  3  7 10 15 14 14  8 17
 2:  2  6  6  8  3  8  7  1  4  7  8 14 11  8 11
 3:  6  4  7  4  4  3  4  6  3  3 10 11  7 10  6
 4:  1  2  4  2  9  9  3  7 10  4  3  6 18 10 14
 5:  9 10  8  1  8  7 10  5  9  1 19  9 15 15 10
 6:  8  8 10  6  2  5  2  4  2  6 16 16  7  6  8
 7:  7  9  1  7  5 10  9  2  1  8 16  8 15 11  9
 8:  5  1  2  9  7  2  1  8  5  5  6 11  9  9 10
 9:  3  7  3  3  1  6  8 10  8  9 10  6  7 18 17
10:  4  3  5 10  6  1  6  9  6  2  7 15  7 15  8
```

---

A similar solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
df %>% 
  bind_cols(., df %>% 
              gather(var, val) %>% 
              group_by(var) %>% 
              mutate(let = substr(var,1,1), rn = 1:n()) %>% 
              group_by(let,rn) %>% 
              summarise(s3 = sum(val)) %>% 
              spread(let, s3) %>% 
              select(-rn)
            )
```

---

However, as noted by @Gregor, it is much better to transform your data into long format. The `data.table` equivalent of @Gregor's answer:

```
DT <- data.table(df)
melt(DT[, rn := .I], 
     variable.name = 'let',
     measure.vars = patterns('1$','2$'), 
     value.name = paste0('v',1:2)
     )[, `:=` (let = letters[let], v3 = v1 + v2)][]
```

which gives (first 15 rows):

```
    rn let v1 v2 v3
 1:  1   a 10  5 15
 2:  2   a  2  6  8
 3:  3   a  6  4 10
 4:  4   a  1  2  3
 5:  5   a  9 10 19
 6:  6   a  8  8 16
 7:  7   a  7  9 16
 8:  8   a  5  1  6
 9:  9   a  3  7 10
10: 10   a  4  3  7
11:  1   b  9  5 14
12:  2   b  6  8 14
13:  3   b  7  4 11
14:  4   b  4  2  6
15:  5   b  8  1  9
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data format is making this hard - I would reshape the data like this. In general, you shouldn't encode actual data information in column names, if the difference between `a1` and `a2` is meaningful, it is better to have a column with letter, `a, b, c` and a column with number, `1, 2`.

```
df$id = 1:nrow(df)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tdf = gather(df, key = key, value = value, -id) %>%
    separate(key, into = c("letter", "number"), sep = 1) %>%
    mutate(number = paste0("V", number)) %>%
    spread(key = number, value = value) 
## now data is "tidy":
head(tdf)
#   id letter V1 V2
# 1  1      a  2  7
# 2  1      b 10  4
# 3  1      c  9 10
# 4  1      d  9  4
# 5  1      e  5  8
# 6  2      a  9  8

## and the operation is simple:
tdf$V3 = tdf$V1 + tdf$V2
head(tdf)
#    id letter V1 V2 V3
# 1   1      a  2  7  9
# 2   1      b 10  4 14
# 3   1      c  9 10 19
# 4   1      d  9  4 13
# 5   1      e  5  8 13
# 6   2      a  9  8 17
```

Comment: I've included a `data.table` version of your answer in mine. Feel free to include it in yours (if you do so, I will remove it from mine).

Comment: I think it's just fine in your answer, but thanks for the offer!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
reduce(.init=df, .x=letters[1:5], .f~{
    mutate(.x, '{.y}3' := get(str_c(.y, 1)) + get(str_c(.y, 2)))
})
```